# select the first picture from all the pictures present in a directory

Tags: php

i made a function in which it prints all the file names with path inside a directory. but i want only first image to be fetched and if there is no image inside the directory print a custom path with a image . any help on this ?

```
function getphotos($album_name)
{
    //path to directory to scan
    $dir = ROOTPATH . "/data/img/gallery/$album_name/";

    //get all files
    $images = glob($dir . "{*.jpg,*.gif,*.jpeg}", GLOB_BRACE);

$ret = "";

    foreach($images as $image)
    {
        $ret .= '<img src="'.$image.'" />';
    }

   return $ret;
}
```

Comment: Try using `break;` in `foreach`, set a variable to 0 and `increment` that in `foreach` and when it is 1 break out of loop

Comment: What's wrong with just using `$images[0]`?

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the suggestion it works but gives error when no image is there

Comment: Can't you just test for the existence of $images[0] before using it?  Or do a `count($images) > 0`?

Comment: Then check whether `count($images) > 0` first, and show the default image instead. Is this so difficult?

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the help and sorry for being a noob. thanks for help.

Comment: OK even being a noob at some point and asking for help here it does not means now everyone will negative vote the questions . come on i didnt asked to make a code for me . i was stuck at some point and thought i could get help here but instead people are negative voting . thats not supportive at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ret = '<img src="' . (empty($images) ? DEFAULTIMG : $images[0]) . '/>';
```